# How does a HttpRequestMessage looks like?

Tags: .net, httprequest

**How does a HttpRequestMessage looks like?**
Web sites call controllers with theses type of messages I believe.
I just learned there is a "body" to these messages.
So this also mean there is an header.
An example of one HttpRequestMessage would help see if there is something else to these messages (a footer for example).

Extra question : Are these messages also used when calling an "HttpGet" method of the controller? They do with "HttpPost"

*** Edit *** : I don't have any problem with them. So this question isn't related with messages of my website. I just want to know how they looks. When I asked the question I taught they were XML message, but reading the documentation cited by @Dark Falcon, I realize that it is "CRLF" oriented.

**The answer should be a copy and paste of one message no matter what it is.**

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, your question is old. That's no reason for me though, to not answer it. As it is no reason for all the SO users to not read it :-)

> HTTP messages consist of requests from a client to a server and
> responses from a server to a client.

A HTTP **request** message have the following structure:

```
<request method> <request target> HTTP/<protocol version>
<header name>: <header value>,<header value>
...
<header name>: <header value>,<header value>
empty line
<message body>
```

So, a request message begins with a "request line" containing:

- the `request method`: 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', etc;
- the `request target`: usually either an absolute URI or a path on the web server;
- the HTTP `protocol version`: 1.0, or 1.1, or 2 (in the future).

Then it continues with a list of headers, followed by an empty line and, at last, the message body.

HTTP request message examples:

With `POST`:

```
POST /controller/action HTTP/1.1
Host: yourdemomvc.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

firstname=hello&lastname=world
```

The message body consists of the input names and values send by submitting a form with the method `POST`.

With `GET`:

```
GET /index.php?firstname=hello&lastname=world HTTP/1.1
Host: yourdemomvc.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
```

The request target in the request line (so, in the first line) displays not only the path, but also the query string (if it's set).

So, yes. These messages are used with all HTTP request methods, including `GET`. Their structure remains the same.

In the tutorial you'll also find an example of a request containing an XML body.

For completion, a HTTP response message looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

The message body in response to the user request.
```

Resources (in addition to the one provided by @DarkFalcon):

- [HTTP/1.1: Message Syntax and Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)
- [HTTP/1.1: Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)
- [HTTP Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to look at http requests and responses and you'll be able to see exactly what they're made up of as you test calling your web services or similar. Tools like this are very useful to understand and debug http based technologies.

Comment: This tool is way way too much for what I need. Taught, I probably could get my answer with it.

Comment: It's just as useful a tool for observing http traffic as it is for debugging, and it's very simple to use. Give it a try you may find it answers your question.